# Reading mails from outlook programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to create a program that reads my mail from Microsoft Outlook so that I can move them into different folders based on thier contents. I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook 12.0, which works fine with Outlook 2007.

How do I handle scenario where another user uses Outlook 2010?

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook doesnt the 2010 version work with both 2007 and 2010?

Comment: +1 This is a good question of concern. I'm just getting serious about reading and parsing Outlook emails programatically using C#. I shall post anything that might help, if you didn't yet find anything useful on the matter.

Comment: Thanks,please do post. I have changed my approach altogether for this. However, it would be nice to know the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use C#? If you don't need to use C#, you can open one of the messages that you need to move and click on "add rule". There you can define rules to, for example, move all mail from your boss into a folder called work. I don't see why you need to use C#. It would be very difficult to do that in C# except simulating mouse movements...